tsconfig.json extends from base not found
I'm trying to setup a new project where I want to use typescript (and eslint, prettier and jest but that's less important). I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sswKgneCVI
However in the tsconfig.json file I get an error. The way I have set up the project:
yarn init
yarn add typescript
yarn add ts-node @types/node @tsconfig/node20 --dev
touch tsconfig.json

I've got the following tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

It fails to resolve @tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json and VS code show the following message when I hover over it: File '@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json' not found.
I am on a Mac, using Yarn 4.5.1 and node v20.18.0 (used nvm to install it).
I can't find anything on the internet, but could this be caused yarn using zero-installs?
Installed everything according to above shell scripts and didn't expect an error.

It's the way yarn manages packages. Yarn uses zip files in the .yarn folder, so whoever is trying to access the dependencies (e.g. editor extensions) won't be able to access them because they'll be looking for the node_modules folder. And Yarn provides some workarounds for this.
1. Setting up the IDE SDKs.
If you didn't setup the IDE SDKs, follow this instruction: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks.
2. Unplug the package.
In most cases, setting up the SDKs will fix the problem. But if it doesn't, you can try unpacking the package. This unpacks a zip dependency so that everyone can access it without Yarn.
yarn unplug @tsconfig/node20

The unplugged dependency locates at .yarn/unplugged (unless you change the config).
Now, change your config like this:
{
  "extends": "./.yarn/unplugged/@tsconfig-node20-npm-20.1.4-34948615bc/node_modules/@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json"
}

The unplugged folder contains a random (I guess) hex value, so make sure it's yours. Also, unless you're using zero install, this is not a perfect method, since everyone has to do it again.
3. Just copy the base tsconfig.json
If I were you, I would just copy the base tsocnfig file and paste it directly. A lot of people do this because they want to reduce the number of dependencies, and it's easy to maintain configs. So, it's totally fine.
Visit https://github.com/tsconfig/bases and choose the base file, and copy compilerOptions.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "node16",
    "target": "es2022",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16"
  }
}

https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node20.json

Yarn cache might be causing your issue, try clearing the cache yarn cache clean and installing with yarn add @tsconfig/node20 --dev, then run yarn install
Hopefully, this solves your issue. I tried this on my mac and it works

That doesn't help sadly enough
